# django - How to save the uploaded file to a spefic folder specifying a name

Tags: django, file-upload

I have a form that the user fills, submits and uploads a file with the same ID from the form. There is a table with the user name and the name of the supervisor. (user -supervisor). I want the user uploaded files to be saved in a folder under the name of the supervisor. Is this possible in django?

Comment: upload_to is what you are looking for. link for the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Comment: Now the files are uploaded to a folder, i want to know how to redirect the files to be saved inside the user's supervisor folder. if there exists a table with the user name and supervisor name

Answer (score 1):

```
def upload_path_handler(instance):
    return "<your path to folder>/{file}".format(id=instance.user.supervisor)

class Profile(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_handler, null=True, blank=True)
```

If your media root is '/media/' and inside media folder, a folder named "supervisor" and inside Supervisor all folders with supervisor's name. then use this:

```
return "supervisors/{file}".format(id=instance.user.supervisor)
```

I don't know how user and supervisor is related in model so replace `instance.user.supervisor` with user's supervisor appropriately. I have used this in project. this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using below code:

```
import uuid

# generate unique name of image file
unique_filename = str(uuid.uuid4())

# assign file name
model.field_name = unique_filename  # model is model object

# save image in temp directory
model.field_name.save(unique_filename, file_content)

# image URL
file_url = settings.MEDIA_FILES + '/folder_name/' + unique_filename

model.save()
```

It will save the file into the folder.